Cannot change the default indexType from AutoIndex to HNSW when creating an index in the Milvus collection via the RESTful API
I have successfully created a Milvus collection and inserted data directly without any noticeable challenges. Now, I want to create a Milvus collection using the RESTful API as detailed in the documentation at Create Collection.
I utilized the following code, which I adapted from the provided link, to create the collection, configure it, insert data, and then create an index.
import time
import requests
import json
import numpy as np

def generate_random_vector():
    float_array = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, 512)
    normalized_array = float_array / np.linalg.norm(float_array, ord=2)
    return normalized_array

def create_collection(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/collections/create"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "collectionName": collection_name,
        "dimension": 512,
        "metricType": "COSINE",
        "vectorFieldName": "Embedding_Features",
        "primaryFieldName": "IDs_Features",
        "idType": "Int64",
        "indexType": "HNSW",
        "primaryKey": {"name": "IDs_Features", "type": "INT64", "primaryKey": True},
        "vectorField": {
            "name": "Embedding_Features",
            "type": "FLOAT_VECTOR",
            "primaryKey": False,
        },
        "indexes": [{
            "fieldName": "Embedding_Features",
            "indexName": "Embedding_Features",
            "metricType": "COSINE",
        }],
        "auto_index": False,
    })
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def validate_collection(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/collections/describe"
    payload = json.dumps({"collectionName": collection_name})
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def drop_collection(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/collections/drop"
    payload = json.dumps({"collectionName": collection_name})
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def insert_data_into_collection(
    collection_name: str,
    start_id: int,
    n: int,
    ids_name: str,
    features_name: str,
    server_address: str,
):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/entities/insert"
    data = [{"IDs_Features": start_id + i + 1, "Embedding_Features": list(generate_random_vector())} for i in range(n)]
    payload = json.dumps({"data": data, "collectionName": collection_name})
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def describe_collection(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/collections/describe"
    payload = json.dumps({"collectionName": collection_name})
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def describe_index(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/indexes/describe"
    payload = json.dumps({"indexName": "Embedding_Features", "collectionName": collection_name})
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

def create_index(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/indexes/create"
    payload = json.dumps({
        "collectionName": collection_name,
        "indexParams": [{
            "metricType": "COSINE",
            "index_type": "HNSW",
            "fieldName": "Embedding_Features",
            "params": {"M": 128, "efConstruction": 256},
        }],
    })
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    return response.json()

When I attempted to create the collection using:
create_collection(collection_name=collection_name, server_address=server_address)

I received the following message:
{'code': 0, 'data': {}}

Subsequently, when I described the collection:
describe_collection(collection_name=collection_name, server_address=server_address)

I got this response:
{'code': 0,
 'data': {'aliases': [],
  'autoId': False,
  'collectionID': 454176377651168636,
  'collectionName': 'collection1',
  'consistencyLevel': 'Bounded',
  'description': '',
  'enableDynamicField': True,
  'fields': [{'autoId': False,
    'clusteringKey': False,
    'description': '',
    'id': 100,
    'name': 'IDs_Features',
    'nullable': False,
    'partitionKey': False,
    'primaryKey': True,
    'type': 'Int64'},
   {'autoId': False,
    'clusteringKey': False,
    'description': '',
    'id': 101,
    'name': 'Embedding_Features',
    'nullable': False,
    'params': [{'key': 'dim', 'value': '512'}],
    'partitionKey': False,
    'primaryKey': False,
    'type': 'FloatVector'}],
  'functions': None,
  'indexes': [{'fieldName': 'Embedding_Features',
    'indexName': 'Embedding_Features',
    'metricType': 'COSINE'}],
  'load': 'LoadStateLoading',
  'partitionsNum': 1,
  'properties': [],
  'shardsNum': 1},
 'message': ''}

When I described the collection index:
describe_index(collection_name=collection_name, server_address=server_address)

I received this message:
{'code': 0,
 'data': [{'failReason': '',
   'fieldName': 'Embedding_Features',
   'indexName': 'Embedding_Features',
   'indexState': 'Finished',
   'indexType': 'AUTOINDEX',
   'indexedRows': 0,
   'metricType': 'COSINE',
   'pendingRows': 0,
   'totalRows': 0}]}

This indicated that the index type was set to AUTOINDEX, despite my configuration specifying HNSW, which caused issues with indexing.
Afterwards, I inserted 10,000 rows into the collection:
number_vectors = 10000
for i in range(0, number_vectors, 500):
    response = insert_data_into_collection(
        collection_name=collection_name,
        start_id=i,
        n=500,
        ids_name="IDs_Features",
        features_name="Embedding_Features",
        server_address=server_address,
    )
    if response["data"]["insertCount"] == 500:
        print(f"Great! inserted ids {i} to {i+500} successfully")
    else:
        print(f"There are some errors for {i}")
    time.sleep(1)

Finally, when I tried to create the index:
create_index(collection_name=collection_name, server_address=server_address)

I encountered the following error:
{'code': 65535, 'message': 'only metric type can be passed when use AutoIndex'}

Is it possible for me to set the indexType to HNSW and either ignore or remove the default AutoIndex value?
By adjusting the create_index function:
def create_index(collection_name: str, server_address: str):
    url = f"{server_address}/v2/vectordb/indexes/create"

    payload = json.dumps(
        {
            "collectionName": collection_name,
            "indexParams": [
                {
                    "metricType": "COSINE",
                    "fieldName": "Embedding_Features",
                    "params": {"M": 128, "efConstruction": 256, "index_type": "HNSW"},
                }
            ],
        }
    )
    # Example: {'metric_type': 'IP', 'index_type': 'HNSW', 'params': {'nlist': 1024, 'efConstruction': 40, 'M': 1024}}
    headers = {
        "x-api-key": "YOUR_API_KEY",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    }

    response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, data=payload)
    response = json.loads(response.text)
    return response

I encountered the following error:
{'code': 65535,
 'message': 'CreateIndex failed: at most one distinct index is allowed per field'}

